# Characters for diagonal lines

Tags: unicode, ascii

I am looking for diagonal lines (from top-left to bottom-right, and from bottom-left to right-top).  They should take the width same as an ASCII letter.

I see something like `⟋`, which takes the width of two ASCII letters.

Which characters are diagonal lines that take just the width of one ASCII letter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 10):

```
//        ⎹          ╱               ⟋            ⎽⎼⎻⎺                                       
//        |         ╱              ⟋           ⎽⎼⎻⎺                                          
//        ⎸        ╱             ⟋          ⎽⎼⎻⎺                                             
//       ⎹        ╱            ⟋         ⎽⎼⎻⎺       _-‾                                      
//       |       ╱           ⟋        ⎽⎼⎻⎺       _-‾               __---‾‾         _⎽⎽⎼⎼⎻⎻⎺⎺ 
//       ⎸      ╱          ⟋       ⎽⎼⎻⎺       _-‾           __---‾‾         _⎽⎽⎼⎼⎻⎻⎺⎺‾       
//      ⎹      ╱         ⟋      ⎽⎼⎻⎺       _-‾       __---‾‾       _⎽⎽⎼⎼⎻⎻⎺⎺‾                
//      |     ╱        ⟋     ⎽⎼⎻⎺       _-‾   __---‾‾       _⎽⎽⎼⎼⎻⎻⎺⎺‾                       
//      ⎸    ╱       ⟋    ⎽⎼⎻⎺                                                               
//          ╳      ⤫                                                                         
//      ⎸    ╲       ⟍    ⎺⎻⎼⎽          ‾-_   ‾‾---__       ‾⎺⎺⎻⎻⎼⎼⎽⎽_                       
//      |     ╲        ⟍     ⎺⎻⎼⎽          ‾-_       ‾‾---__        ‾⎺⎺⎻⎻⎼⎼⎽⎽_               
//      ⎹      ╲         ⟍      ⎺⎻⎼⎽          ‾-_           ‾‾---__        ‾⎺⎺⎻⎻⎼⎼⎽⎽_        
//       ⎸      ╲          ⟍       ⎺⎻⎼⎽          ‾-_                ‾‾---__       ‾⎺⎺⎻⎻⎼⎼⎽⎽_ 
//       |       ╲           ⟍        ⎺⎻⎼⎽          ‾-_                                      
//       ⎹        ╲            ⟍         ⎺⎻⎼⎽                                                
//        ⎸        ╲             ⟍          ⎺⎻⎼⎽                                             
//        |         ╲              ⟍           ⎺⎻⎼⎽ 
//        ⎹          ╲               ⟍
```

Answer (score 4):

[Slash](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/slash-forward-slash-fraction-bar-division-ascii-code-47.html) (ASCII code 47) and [Backslash](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/backslash-reverse-slash-ascii-code-92.html) (ASCII code 92)

Answer (score 3):

These work on my browser, but the displayed glyph width depends on the font, not the Unicode code point.  In a proportional font, ASCII i is narrower than ASCII M (iMiMiM).

Below is displayed on a proportional font and are very wide on my browser:

> ╱ U+2571 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER RIGHT TO LOWER LEFT
> ╲ U+2572 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER LEFT TO LOWER RIGHT

But a fixed font they are the same as ASCII on my browser:

```
╱ U+2571 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER RIGHT TO LOWER LEFT
╲ U+2572 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER LEFT TO LOWER RIGHT
```

Python example:

```py
>>> print('\u2571\u2572'*5);print('ABCDEabcde')
╱╲╱╲╱╲╱╲╱╲
ABCDEabcde
```